# What's the geom_abline() equivalent in echarts4r?

Tags: r, charts, echarts4r

I'm trying to plot a scatterplot using e_scatter with a benchmark line that should go from (0,0) to (1,1) on the chart

````
```
compare () %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("Brand") %>% 
  e_charts(Benchmark) %>% 
  e_scatter(Actual,symbol_size = 10,bind = Name) %>% 
  e_labels(formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("function(params) {
  return(params.name)
      }")) %>% 
  e_mark_line(data = list(xAxis = 0)) %>% 
  e_tooltip()

```
````

Comment: Have tried e_mark_line but could not find any reference for a diagonal line

Comment: Hi, can you please provide a dataset so we can reproduce your plot?

Answer (score 0):

```
compare() %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("Brand") %>% 
  mutate(New = Benchmark) %>% 
  e_charts(Benchmark) %>% 
  e_scatter(Actual,symbol_size = 10,bind = Brand) %>% 
  e_labels(formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("function(params) {
  return(params.name)
}")) %>% 
  e_lm(New~Benchmark) %>% 
  e_tooltip() %>% 
  e_axis_labels(x ="Benchmark", y = "Actual")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).